# Can an HTML <select> element have a default selectedIndex of -1 without running page-wide javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have several places in my website where a "combobox" style control is needed.  To do this, I've encapsulated the combobox control into a .NET server-side component for re-usability.  Some pages may have a combobox on them, some may not.

At the core, this combobox contains a textbox and a "dropdown" aligned appropriately with CSS.  Part of the HTML rendered is simply:

```
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

The dropdown must start off empty, and changing to any value (including "Option 1") must trigger the onchange event.

I accomplish this by doing something like:

```
document.getElementById("theSelectElement").selectedIndex = -1;
```

but I'd prefer not to have to run javascript against each element on the page.  I realize that I could use jQuery to select against a CSS class, but most pages won't have a select element on it and nothing will happen.

Is there a way to set selectedIndex that's encapsulated in the tag itself?  Something like:

```
<select selectedIndex="-1">...
```

or

```
<select onload="this.selectedIndex = -1">...
```

?

Comment: Can you not add an empty option as the first one?

Comment: "page wide" JavaScript is not so terrible.. what are you afraid of? Even without jQuery, script to set `selectedIndex` of all drop downs is very few lines and won't cause any slowness.

Comment: couldn't you change the value of the selected index server side with an option in the control?

Comment: @DoozerBlake adding an empty option is different than setting selectedIndex = -1.  An empty option can be re-selected after you've selected another option.

Answer (score 3):

a select is a radio state holder so there is no "non-selected" state

```
<select name="aaa">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

btw you can use an empty < option >

Comment: hm... interesting (just fyi I'm not the OP and am just curious).  Do you have a link to some documentation on that first point?  Also, if that's the case, what exactly happens when you select -1 with javascript?

Comment: What is a 'radio state'? I understand what you mean by it, but never heard the term. What does radio represent in this case?

Comment: The blank first <option> works ok, but the idea of the combobox is to show the user possible values they can select.  The blank appears at the top of the possible selections.  If you use selectedIndex = -1, there's no possibility to select a blank value, it just starts out empty.

Comment: @wes not *quite* a radio-state holder, consider `<select name="emails" size="3" multiple="multiple">`... but very close to it, true. Both `radio`s and `select`s, as you point, start with nothing selected but do not let you "unselect" once you make a choice.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following: By default the first option will be selected automatically

```
<select name="aaa">
    <option value="0">select any option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yeah, but I need the default value to be empty (it's part of how a standard combobox is expected to work)

Comment: then set the `value` property of the first `option` as empty. And if you don't need the text either of the first option then go for the @wes asnwwer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some documentation of select: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6

Answer (score -1):

If you've wrapped it in your own user control or custom control then you'll need to expose the `defaultSelection` property (or whatever you name it) publicly so it can be specified in your server tag.

You talk about doing it in a `<select>` tag, but this is the HTML markup - not the server-side markup of `<ASP:DropDown ... >` or `<myControl:CustomSelect ... >`

**EDIT :** If it's pure HTML, then just output the default selection with the `selected` property set:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Top</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="-1">Middle (Empty)</option>
    <option value="2">End</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that's true, but not really the point of the question.  I'm really asking how the rendered HTML can accomplish the goal of having a blank initial state.